# Scores for tagged NER results in the StandfordCore NLP.net library

Tags: stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I'm using the Sandford CoreNLP.NET module and its CRFClassifier to find Named Entities in a document. I am able to get the entities by using classifyWithInlineXML, but does anyone know how to get the entities along with their relevance/confidence scores (0-1)?

Would love an example in C# on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a duplicate of [Display Stanford NER confidence score](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26612999/display-stanford-ner-confidence-score) question.

All you need is to rewrite provided sample in C#.

Comment: Awesome thanks Sergey, I'll take a look and try write up a C# translation

Comment: Just another question, the confidence score doesn't indicate relevance does it? Are they the same concept?

Comment: It actually depend on what you mean by relevancy. Stanford NER returns " likelihood of each possible label at each point".